# eclipse marketplace proxy authentication

Tags: eclipse, plugins, proxy, eclipse-marketplace

I've downloaded eclipse with the properties described at the appendix below.
When I try to download a plugin using the eclipse marketplace, such as Moonrise UI Theme or Color Theme, It doesn't work and prompts "HTTP Proxy Authentication Required" error box. No info other than the plug-in's eclipse website is available. I can not install an eclipse plug-in.

--- Appendix---
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800
recently downloaded using zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to configure Eclipse to authenticate against your proxy. Open the preferences dialog and select **General > Network Connections**. Pick "HTTP", hit **Edit** and enter the details. If you don't know those, you should talk with someone within your company or group that do know.